# What is direction of induced current in a rotating rod pivoted at one end in a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

This is rod of length l, placed on metallic ring of the same radius as rod's length. This set up is placed in a magnetic field perpendicular to the rod and into the plane.

It is very clear that an emf will be created in the rotating rod. I have two questions:
(i) What is the direction of the induced current in the rod (and in metallic ring if any)
(ii) What is the purpose of having this metallic ring? Can't the rod alone do the job?

Comment: There can only be a current in the rod if there is a source of charge at one end and a sink at the other. Unless you are talking about a transient current as the ends of the rod acquire charge. Typically current flows in accordance with the emf. Is there any context to the question ("what is the purpose of the ring?"). There is no purpose to the rod either... What is "the job" you are trying to do.

Comment: It's a derivation generally provided in books to demonstrate the concept of motional emf. As regards to motional emf, the rod alone is sufficient to explain the concept, ain't it?

Comment: In that case yes, you don't need the ring

Comment: What could be the use of the ring? Would the current flow in the ring? Isn't this an open circuit?

Comment: Maybe the ring is used another part of the question? Maybe it is there to show that a "moving" loop doesn't always experience an emf? I just don't know